# Webpack Build generates index.html but blank when loaded in browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Please find my repo@ https://github.com/reachlinlen/empexplorer Webpack configuration is https://github.com/reachlinlen/empexplorer/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Why index.html is not rendering the pages after npm run build? Does Tailwind css is causing any issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is good with your build (but don't forget to add "axios" in dependencies). You need to use a HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter if you want your application will work with static file server (like [www.test.com/path/index.html](http://www.test.com/path/index.html)).

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-doesnt-my-application-render-after-refreshing

Comment: Perfectly working. Many Thanks. But https://github.com/lewislbr/gauzy-react-app in this repo, BrowserRoute is used but still renders. How?

Comment: It renders only header but not router content. BrowserRouter doesn't work with local file protocol (file://path/index.html). It's normal behavior so you don't need do change your router to HashRouter (we used it to check that is all fine with the bundle). You will get all static content from server and BrowserRouter will work.

Answer (score 0):

I found another way to serve the webpack 5 build version.

In terminal

```sh
npm i -g http-server

cd dist && http-server
```

Now your build version should be on `http://127.0.0.1:8080`.

I hope this can help someone who is still bothering by this issue.